# Datetime Subtraction without taking count of currentDateTime and year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Iam newbie in writing some complex queries. Iam having a table with three columns orgid, EndDateTime, PreviousDateTime. The EndDateTime and PreviousDateTime willnot have the currentDate. The DateTime differs from 2006 to  2015.I need a query to update previousDateTime to EndDateTime and PreviousDateTime to one year less than DateTime present in PreviousDateTime column. There is one more condition like if PreviousDatetime is null then two things to be updated

- EndDatetime should be updated with one year less than the datetime
  present in EndDatetime
- PreviousDateTime should be update one year less than the EndDateTime
  after it is reduced to one year.

Can any one help me out this?

This question is different from already asked question like

- In already asked question they are calculating from the
  currentDatetime and year.
- This question needs to be done for already dateTime is exists in that table   from that calculation has to be done..

Comment: some reading would help you much more, look at the docs for date and time functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: UPDATE yourtable
SET
  EndDatetime = dateadd(year, -1, EndDatetime),
  PreviousDateTime = dateadd(year, -2, EndDatetime) WHERE PreviousDatetime is null

Comment: this will update if previousDatetime is null, if previousenddatetime is not null then i need to subtract one year from it.. Can i get both in one update query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
update table 
set EndDateTime=case when PreviousDateTime is null then DATEADD(y,-1,EndDateTime) else PreviousDateTime end,
PreviousDateTime=case when PreviousDateTime is null then DATEADD(y,-2,EndDateTime) else end DATEADD(y,-1,PreviousDateTime)
```

Comment: But instead of  datediff  i have used dateadd which gives the one year less than already present year value in EndDateTime column         update table 
    set EndDateTime = 
 case when PreviousDateTime is null 
 then dateadd(year, -1, EndDateTime) 
 else PreviousDateTime 
 end
    ,PreviousDateTime = 
 case when PreviousDateTime is null 
 then dateadd(year, -2,EndDateTime) 
 else dateadd(year, -1, PreviousDateTime) 
 end

Comment: yes. you are correct.. it should be DATEADD. thanks for correcting me. (edited my answer)